# How to save Captured Images to Custom path in android Storage

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-storage

I have built an Camera application following a Tutorial from Youtube. It saves the Files on External Storage with following code

```
public void takePicture(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    file = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
}

private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CameraDemo");

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("CameraDemo", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            imageView.setImageURI(file);
        }
    }
}
```

But, I would like to show a Dialog box to user when app starts with directory chooser dialog where they want to save images which I followed the Tutorial from this link https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/547636/Android-Ready-to-use-simple-directory-chooser-dial

The code for Directory choose dialog is below

```
DirectoryChooserDialog directoryChooserDialog =
    new DirectoryChooserDialog(MainActivity.this,
        new DirectoryChooserDialog.ChosenDirectoryListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onChosenDir(String chosenDir)
            {
                m_chosenDir = chosenDir;
                Toast.makeText(
                    MainActivity.this, "Chosen directory: " +
                    chosenDir, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
// Toggle new folder button enabling
directoryChooserDialog.setNewFolderEnabled(m_newFolderEnabled);
// Load directory chooser dialog for initial 'm_chosenDir' directory.
// The registered callback will be called upon final directory selection.
directoryChooserDialog.chooseDirectory(m_chosenDir);
m_newFolderEnabled = ! m_newFolderEnabled;
```

And also indeed, I have a separate class of DirectoryChooserDialog.

Now how do I merge the first code with second one such that when Image taken from camera will save to the folder that users selected from second code not to external storage Directory as specified by first code.

Image file for DirectoryChooserDialog appears as

[image: DirectoryChooserDialog]